# Entity Framework 5: Context updated, but not View

Tags: c#-4.0, view, entity-framework-5

I use Unit of Work and Repository patterns in my software.
There is a dataGridView on form and it gets data from next way:

```
acceptedBonusesGrid.DataSource = _unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetDocumentsInfo();
```

GetDocumentsInfo is in DocumentRepository. GetDocumentsInfoes - is complex view with joins:

```
public IQueryable<GetDocumentsInfo> GetDocumentsInfo()
{
     return _context.GetDocumentsInfoes;
}
```

When user double-clicks on record, it's form for editing this record appears. I send unit of work to form:

```
CorrectionAcceptedForm corrForm = new CorrectionAcceptedForm(_unitOfWork, docNum);
```

Form opens and link to unit of work is in use:

```
public CorrectionAcceptedForm(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, int docNum)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

    _documentData = _unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetById(docNum);

    AssignValues();
}
```

User makes changes in the record and saves changes:

```
private void SaveBill(int billId)
{
    if (ValidateChildren())
    {
        SaveSupplierAddress();
        Bill billData = _documentData.Bills.FirstOrDefault(bill => bill.BillId == billId);
        if (billData != null)
        {
            billData.Description = descriptionTextbox.Text;
            billData.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(priceTextbox.Text.Replace('.', ','));
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

When this correction form closes, then datagrid on main form reloads:

```
acceptedBonusesGrid.DataSource = null;
acceptedBonusesGrid.Columns.Clear();
acceptedBonusesGrid.DataSource = _unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetDocumentsInfo();
```

But after reload - all rows in datagrid are old, that was before making changes.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months I have discovered problem. 
GetDocumentsInfo() has to be like this:

```
    public IQueryable<GetDocumentsInfo> GetDocumentsInfo()
    {
        _context.GetDocumentsInfoes.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        return _context.GetDocumentsInfoes;
    }
```

Now my DataGrid updates when I make changes in child form.